# printing and storing to vector of type class

Tags: c++, class, object, vector

I want to store the values of p1 and p2 into vector vip and print vip using the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Person.h"
#include "Daglejer.h"
#include "Funktionaer.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Person p1("Mads", 21);
    Person p2("Carl", 23);
    Person p3("Thomas", 32);
    Person p4("Magnus", 8);
    Person p5("Joe", 81);

    vector <Person>vip;
    vip.push_back(p1);
    vip.push_back(p2);
    vector<Person>::iterator i;
    for(i = vip.begin(); i != vip.end(); i++)
        cout << vip[i];

    return 0;
}
```

The header file Person.h contains the following:

```
#ifndef PERSON_H_
#define PERSON_H_
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Person {
private:
    string navn;
    int alder;

public:
    Person(string, int);
    Person();
    void setNavn(string);
    string getNavn();
    void setAlder(int);
    int getAlder();
};

#endif /* PERSON_H_ */
```

and the cpp file:

```
#include "Person.h"
using namespace std;

Person::Person(){

}

Person::Person(string name, int age) {
setNavn(name);
setAlder(age);
}

void Person::setNavn(string name){
navn = name;
}

void Person::setAlder(int age){
alder = age;
}

string Person::getNavn(){
    return navn;
}
int Person::getAlder() {
    return alder;
}
```

When I compile I get the following error:

> no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'std::vector' and 'std::vector::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >}')

at the line where i use cout. I've searched a lot on stackoverflow and several other websites, but the solutions given didn't solve my problem. I hope someone can help me. 
Thanks in advance. 
Mads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to call the subscript operator when iterating over a list, just dereference the iterator itself.

```
for(i = vip.begin(); i != vip.end(); i++)
        cout << *i;
```

Additionally you'll either need to add a non-member overload of << to Person, or just call the getters on what you want to display.

```
for(i = vip.begin(); i != vip.end(); i++)
        cout << i->getNavn();
```

Comment: With the C++11 [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) it's even easier: `for (const auto& i : vip) cout << i.getNavn();`

Comment: And then a stream operator for Person is still missing.

Answer (score 0):

`ostream` has no concept of what `Person` is supposed to output to. You need to overload the `ostream` or reference the field you want specifically.

i.e., either:

```
cout << i->getNavn() << " " << i->getAlder() << endl;
```

or

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Person& p)
{
    os << p.getAlder() << '--' << p.getNavn() << endl;
    return os;
}
```